# GLInfo & AWTWindowProgram imports with OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I've been set a graphics project as part of a Computer Graphics module, to familiarise myself with the basics of Open GL I've been following some of the tutorials from this website https://sites.google.com/site/justinscsstuff/

At the moment I'm working through a tutorial about rendering methods (https://sites.google.com/site/justinscsstuff/rendering-methods/triangle-scene). In the extended block of sample code for the class 'TriangleScene' there are two imports that I'm a little confused about:

1) support.GLInfo
2) windows.AWTWindowProgram

Eclipse doesn't recognise these automatically - do I need to download further sets of class libraries, as I had to for OpenGL?

I'm just looking to shed some light on these two imports so I can carry on working through the tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need to download these files. You can find them on [this page that you mentioned](https://sites.google.com/site/justinscsstuff/rendering-methods/triangle-scene) down at the bottom (the first and third files in the list).

Comment: D'oh! Pages worth of googling, and the files were under my nose!